# Mime.cache error usr/share/mime and could not log in user account(Keep asking password)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mime-types

I accidentally remove the mime.cache when I installing zoom to my ubuntu(14.04). Right now it does not allow me to login keep asking me a password in a loop even though I write it correctly. I login to root shell prompt while booting and first I update mime

```
sudo update-mime-database /usr/share/mime
```

it did not help at all and later I try to remove mime directory of mime.cache and reinstall it ([This is a solution I found somewhere](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2295431).). However, it only works under read-only mode so does not allow me. I change it with

```
chmod 777 mime.cache
```

Alas, it did not work either, does not allow me to change it to read-write Would you please tell me what should I do to, restore mime, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!
Before deleting mime folder I had its backup just in case with the name of mime_back.
Now, I remount the system to read-write mode with the following command.

```
mount -o remount,rw /
```

and then deleted the recent version of mime with `rm -rf`. Finally, rename the backup mime folder. And it worked.